# Issue with connecting to the mysql database

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, authentication

We have an outstanding issue with VCC in chicago, there is an issue connecting to the mysql database
    If an agent does a  refresh of the monitor they will be logged out.
    This is the error we get when the vcc web server starts.
    [Error: MySQL server is requesting the old and insecure pre-4.1 auth mechanism.Upgrade the user password or use the {insecureAuth: true} option.] code: 'HANDSHAKE_INSECURE_AUTH', fatal: true }
    I have done below step,but this issue still exsit.Please check.
    old_passwords set to off
    ALTER TABLE `agent_login_session` CHANGE `operatorId` `operatorId` VARCHAR( 128 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL – done

```
·         info: socket.io started
###### Session SB Server connected fail! ######
{ [Error: MySQL server is requesting the old and insecure pre-4.1 auth mechanism.Upgrade the user password or use the {insecureAuth: true} option.] code: 'HANDSHAKE_INSECURE_AUTH', fatal: true }

1. update mysql to use long password()
# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=0

2. ALTER TABLE `agent_login_session` CHANGE `operatorId` `operatorId` VARCHAR( 128 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL


Please help me here.
```

Comment: Did this happen after upgrading to MySQL 5.5 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your [**`old_passwords`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_old_passwords) setting, I would ask you to look at three things

1. What password functions return
2. What passwords are stored in `mysql.user`
3. What authentication style is the client launching

## PASSWORD FUNCTIONS

Please run the following:

```
show variables like 'old_passwords';
select password('rolando'),old_password('rolando');
```

Depending on where `old_passwords` is enabled or not, you should get either the following:

MySQL 5.0 with `old_passwords` off

```
mysql> show variables like 'old_passwords';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| old_passwords | OFF   |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select password('rolando'),old_password('rolando');
+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
| password('rolando')                       | old_password('rolando') |
+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
| *C1868CE781FCB521A03168DE044BF3F64E9E485A | 05e97e95241a4409        |
+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

MySQL 5.1 with `old_passwords` on

```
mysql> show variables like 'old_passwords';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| old_passwords | ON    |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select password('rolando'),old_password('rolando');
+---------------------+-------------------------+
| password('rolando') | old_password('rolando') |
+---------------------+-------------------------+
| 05e97e95241a4409    | 05e97e95241a4409        |
+---------------------+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

MySQL 5.5 with `old_passwords` off

```
mysql> show variables like 'old_passwords';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| old_passwords | OFF   |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select password('rolando'),old_password('rolando');
+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
| password('rolando')                       | old_password('rolando') |
+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
| *C1868CE781FCB521A03168DE044BF3F64E9E485A | 05e97e95241a4409        |
+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

MySQL 5.5 with `old_passwords` on

```
mysql> show variables like 'old_passwords';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| old_passwords | ON    |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select password('rolando'),old_password('rolando');
+---------------------+-------------------------+
| password('rolando') | old_password('rolando') |
+---------------------+-------------------------+
| 05e97e95241a4409    | 05e97e95241a4409        |
+---------------------+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## PASSWORDS STORED

Please run this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) password_length_count,password_length FROM
(SELECT LENGTH(password) password_length FROM mysql.user) A
GROUP BY password_length;
```

If you get any `password_length` of 16, you have to enable `old_passwords` for the old style authentication to work.

## PASSWORDS FROM CLIENT

In some cases, using mysql libraries that came from old yum installs of MySQL, PHP, Perl or Apache may have pre-MySQL4.1 user authentication code. Please upgrade such libraries.